# Enable a button when all required radio buttons are checked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to enable a button when all the radio buttons (that are required) are selected. I have an idea of how to do this with a fixed number of options (radio button couple, yes or no). The thing is that the form is generated dynamically using php and the amount of "question" which require the user to answer yes or no using radio buttons are unknown.

This is an html example code generated:

```
<form>
  Generic Privacy Policy
  [*]static global opt1
  <input type="radio" name="ppopt1" value="0" data-req="1"> No
  <input type="radio" name="ppopt1" value="1" data-req="1"> Yes
  [*]static global opt2
  <input type="radio" name="ppopt2" value="0" data-req="1"> No
  <input type="radio" name="ppopt2" value="1" data-req="1"> Yes
  static global opt3
  <input type="radio" name="ppopt3" value="0" data-req="0"> No
  <input type="radio" name="ppopt3" value="1" data-req="0"> Yes
  static global opt4
  <input type="radio" name="ppopt4" value="0" data-req="0"> No
  <input type="radio" name="ppopt4" value="1" data-req="0"> Yes
  <button name="btn" type="button" disabled>Send!</button>
</form>
```

As you can see im using *data-req* to specify if the question needs and answer (and also it needs to be Yes value=1).

How (maybe using jquery) i can enable the button *btn* when the condition is achieved?

PS. I have complete control of the PHP code, so if you consider that some modifications on the php code can simplify the frontend coding be free to suggest.

Comment: When a radio is changed, run a check function to see if all conditions are met, if they are, remove the `button`'s `disabled` attribute.

Comment: My answer is exactly what @AndrewPeacock was suggesting. Andrew  Suggestion got useful up vote. But my answer got down vote. very funny

Comment: if they are required to be `YES` - what's the point of the giving the user an option?

Comment: @wirey legal requirements, it does not have sense, thats whats happens when lawyers touch internet

Comment: @DomingoSL is it always a yes/no option?  if so that would be really easy and short

Comment: @wirey yes. Always Yes or No

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd go about it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $form = $("form"),
        $button = $form.find("button"),
        $radios = $form.find('input[type="radio"]'),
        $requiredRadios = $radios.filter('[data-req="1"]');

    $requiredRadios.on("click", function () {
        var numValid = 0;

        $requiredRadios.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                myName = $this.attr("name"),
                isYes = ($this.val() === "1"),
                $target = (isYes ? $this : $radios.filter('input[name="' + myName + '"][value="1"]'));

            if ($target.prop("checked")) {
                numValid++;
            }
        });

        if (numValid === $requiredRadios.length) {
            $button.prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $button.prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/aCheQ/1/

It finds all required radio buttons, and binds a `click` handler to each of them. When one is clicked, goes through all the required radio buttons, and counts to see if enough "Yes" radio buttons are clicked. If so, it enables the button, otherwise disabling it. I'm sure it could be cleaned up a little, or made more efficient, but it seems to be what's expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
        $requires = $('input:radio[data-req=1][value=1]');

        var checked = 0;
        $requires.each(function () {
            if($(this)[0].checked)
                $("button").attr("disabled", (++checked < $requires.length));
        });
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/qyHDn/)

Answer (score 0):

**Fully tested Code** and working

```
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    var enableButton = false;
    var totalChecked = 0;
  var reqElements  =  $('input:radio[data-req =1]');
    var reqElementsCount= $("input:radio[data-req =1][value=1]").size();
    $(reqElements).each(function (index, ele) {
        if($(ele).is(":checked") && ele.value === "1"){
           totalChecked++;
        }
    });
    if(totalChecked == reqElementsCount){ 
        $("button").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else{
         $("button").attr("disabled",true);
    }
});
```

[**demo at JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/habo/DxVag/4/)

Comment: The "required" checkbox groups need to have their "Yes" checkbox specifically checked - you're not checking for that. And if you start clicking around, your logic doesn't work anyways. It works at first (sometimes). You clearly didn't **fully** test it

Comment: The code just check if the last radio button with the requiered attr is check, it does not control is all are checked, any way i dint down vote your answer

Comment: @Ian may be you did not test my jsFillde demo. It does work, if you continue clicking around. Earlier there was a typo on disabled attribute. I think you got carried away with out insight of the code.

Comment: @DomingoSL i think you are confused. on a click event of of any radio button it check for all radio button of required are checked or not. you can give a shot on jsfiddle link i posted.

Comment: @HaBo Unfortunately no, I tested it, and it doesn't work. And like I said, it doesn't even take the "Yes" ones being required. Don't be mad because your's is wrong and downvote my answer

Comment: please try again your code on JSFiddle, and just answer Yes on the second one and you will see the button goes enabled, this is wrong

Comment: @DomingoSL and Ian, my apologizes for the confusion. I corrected my answer now. This time I think i got it right http://jsfiddle.net/habo/DxVag/4/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following javascript, there is an explanation in the code's comments

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function ()
{
   var req,reqYes;
   req=$('input[type="radio"][data-req="1"][value="1"]').length;
   reqYes=$('input:checked[type="radio"][data-req="1"][value="1"]').length;
   document.getElementsByName("btn")[0].disabled= (req!=reqYes);
   return true;
 }
);

/* - Is onchange because it happens after the click once the radiobutton state has been changed 
   - Is getElementsByName()[0] because you used the name instead the ID (The id is unique, but not the name so it returns an array of objects)
   - No need to do a foreach since you can check the Radiosbutton required and the Required with yes answer, the foreach is done by Jquery
**/
```

Fiddled here http://jsfiddle.net/egorbatik/pVh4U/

Comment: Was in the fiddle or here?

Answer (score 0):

if each group is only going to contain yes/no then you can just check to make sure the number of checked yes radios are half of the total required radios

```
$(function () {
    var req = $('input[data-req=1]');
    req.change(function () {
        // if the checked radios with value=1 amount == half of the total required (because only Yes or No can be checked)
        var allchecked = req.filter('[value=1]:checked').length == req.length/2
        // disable of not all checked - enable if all checked
        $('button').prop('disabled', !allchecked);
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kyMTh/)

If you want to check against the number of groups instead you can loop through and get distinct input names

```
$(function () {
    var req = $('input[data-req=1]');
    var groups = [];
    req.each(function(i,v){
        // if group name not in array add it
        if($.inArray(v.name,groups) == -1){
            groups.push(v.name);
        }
    });
    req.change(function () {
        // if the checked amount == number of groups
        var allchecked = req.filter('[value=1]:checked').length == groups.length;
        // disable of not all checked - enable if all checked
        $('button').prop('disabled', !allchecked);
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw52v/)

Just thought of this one - you can also just check the number of checked YES against the number of elements with data-req=1 and value=1

```
$(function () {
    var req = $('input[data-req=1]');
    req.change(function () {        
        var allchecked = req.filter('[value=1]:checked').length == req.filter('[value=1]').length;
        $('button').prop('disabled', !allchecked);
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hGtTr/)